Is there any version of CFM56 with can combustors?
This lamp is sold online:

They claim it's made from a CFM56 combustion chamber. It looks like a can combustor, and I read everywhere that CFM56 uses an annular combustor.
Is there a version of CFM56 with can combustors?

If yes: is this lamp look like one?
If not: from what engine the body of that lamp would be from?


In short
It's the flame tube of an individual can of a cannular combustor, a mix between can and annular combustors. The can may come from auxiliary power unit turbine or a JT8D powering older Boeing 737 and MD-80 or an . It cannot be from a CFM56, all models use annular combustors.
The three main types of combustors:

Source.
All types are approximately to the same scale, meaning an individual can of a can or a cannular combustor is much smaller than an annular combustor.
The can of the lamp support has interconnectors, pipes used to connect the cans.

Details
Recent Boeing 737 and Airbus A320 can use different engines:

CFM56 models -3B, -5A, -5B, -7B,
IAE V2500,
PW1100G,
LEAP

All have annular combustors, single fuel nozzle (SAC) or dual fuel nozzle (DAC) for NOx reduction. However older versions of Boeing 737, -100 and -200,  used a JT8D engine with 8 cannular combustors, the beast you got. In cannular type, the individual combustion zones share a common annulus casing:

Source.
Detail of a combustor:

Source.
The part making the lamp support is the flame tube (liner) of the combustor. The external air casing has been removed. I wasn't able to identify the exact version of the combustor, there has been multiple improvements over time on the JT8D, a famous engine, still used today.
More information about turbofans (pdf).
